# AVAudioPlayer skipping when returning from Springboard

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I have audio constantly playing during my application.  I am having some odd behavior when I press the button to return to Springboard then resume my applications.  The Audio will continue playing but will skip/cutout every half second or so.  Pausing and resuming the audio seems to have no effect.

I am using AVAudioPlayers to play my Audio.  Here is the code to play them...

```
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&err];
[player play];
player.numberOfLoops = loops;

mSimpleSoundList.push_back(player);
```

Then in the "applicationWillResignActive"  I call...

```
const uint32 size = mSimpleSoundList.size();
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {

    AVAudioPlayer* curElement = mSimpleSoundList.at(i);
    [curElement pause];
}
```

followed by this code on restart..

```
const uint32 size = mSimpleSoundList.size();
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {

    AVAudioPlayer* curElement = mSimpleSoundList.at(i);
    [curElement play];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out to be an AudioUnits fault.

[AudioUnits causing universal skipping after returning from Springboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130443/audiounits-causing-universal-skipping-after-returning-from-springboard)